# Expression Engine install trouble (2.9.2)

Tags: config, install

I seem to be having some trouble getting expression engine to install on my server. I've set everything up as directed and still am having issues with it. When I go to the home page - no matter what I do I still see "Your config file does not appear to be formatted correctly."

So I Double checked the permissions and directories and everything looks fine. I however did notice that the drop down for data base type is completely empty and un selectable ( I don't know if this is a bug).

I can fill out all the information and click create and then the url changes and the browser screen just turns white. It doesn't look like anything is happening (nothing spinning or moving in the browser tabs) but regardless I let it run a few minutes - and nothing. I checked the config and database.php files and both are still blank.

This has been quite frustrating as I have installed EE many times before with no problem at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading!!

EDIT - 
I am using -

centOS: 5
PHP: 5.3.29
apache: 2.2
mySQL: 5.6

I would also like to add - the database type drop down is not populated with anything and I'm thinking that may be a helpful clue.

Comment: From looking at your server set up I can tell that... Oh wait... ;-) Any chance you could post some more details about server set up? PHP version? etc. Are you sure you have all of the install files uploaded too? Maybe try uploading the files again.

Comment: @foamcow I updated with the server setup. If you need anything else let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Have you run the [Server Compatibility Wizard](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html#server-compatibility-wizard)?

Comment: @DerekHogue Yes, was one of the first few things I Tried, it doesn't run - by that I mean I can fill out the form with the db info but when I press ok it just goes to a white screen just like the install process :(.

Comment: To me, that points to your server not meeting the requirements, or something being broken in your server config. I'd check for server error logs, or ask your host about them.